# Rename files in multiple subfolders

Tags: bash

I have multiple unique directories that each contain a file named `filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5`. I want to paste the directory-name onto the filename to make the filename unique within each folder. Is this possible?

```
./sample_scRNA_unsorted_98433_Primary_bam/outs/filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5
./sample_scRNA_unsorted_77570_Primary_bam/outs/filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5
```

out:

```
./sample_scRNA_unsorted_98433_Primary_bam/outs/sample_scRNA_unsorted_98433_Primary_bam_filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5
./sample_scRNA_unsorted_77570_Primary_bam/outs/sample_scRNA_unsorted_77570_Primary_bam_filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
find . -type f -name 'filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5' \
-exec sh -c \
'fp="$1"; d=$(echo "$fp"|cut -d/ -f2); echo $(dirname "$fp")/${d}_$(basename "$fp")' \
-- '{}' \;
```

- `find` allows to iterate the files with relative path
- `-exec` allows to do action on `'{}'` which is the file path
- `sh` is used to simplify the action
- `dirname` and `basename` allows to extract directories or filename.
- `cut` is used to extract only the first directory (second field as the first one is `.`)

To rename:

```sh
find . -type f -name 'filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5' \
-exec sh -c \
'fp="$1"; d=$(echo "$fp"|cut -d/ -f2); mv -v "$fp" "$(dirname "$fp")/${d}_$(basename "$fp")"' \
-- '{}' \;
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to modify this to actually rename. This only prints the intended name but does not change the filenames.

Comment: Instead of `echo` do `mv "$fp" the_rest_of_the_echo`

Answer (score 5):

For completeness here is a solution with only `bash` built-in:

```sh
shopt -s globstar nullglob
name="filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5"
for f in */**/"$name"; do mv "$f" "${f%/*}/${f%%/*}_$name"; done
```